# InnerHtml inject static html with relative href

Tags: angular

I would like to insert this kind of code:

```
template = '<div style="background-image: url("/assets/images/hello_message.png");">TEST</div>'
```

but as soon as I inject it that way:

```
@ViewChild('root', { static: true }) element: HTMLDivElement;


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.template;
}
```

it's getting parsed as

```
<div style="background-image: url(" assets="" images="" hello_message.png");"="">TEST</div>
```

I'm aware it's not safe without any kind of sanitization but I would like to do it that way. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found after a lot of work is to use `Renderer2`

So my code look like this

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

 templateUrl = 'url("/assets/images/hello_message.png")'
 templateDiv = '<div">TEST</div>'

    constructor(private elmRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.templateDiv;
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'background-image',this.templateUrl)    
    }
```

The result

```
<div style="background-image: background-image: url("/assets/images/hello_message.png");>TEST</div>
```

2 option :

```
template = '<div style="background-image: url("/assets/images/hello_message.png");">TEST</div>'

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.element.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', this.
template);
  }
```

Hope useful